# C++ cin or vector clear not work well

Tags: c++, vector

Today I write a simple c++ code, which about vector and pair. The code as following:

```
void printInfo(vector< pair<string, int> >& pair_vec)
{
    cout << "----- Authors' information: ------" << endl;
    vector< pair<string, int> >::const_iterator iter = pair_vec.begin();
    while (iter != pair_vec.end()) {
        cout << iter->first << " " << (*iter).second << endl;
        ++iter;
    }
    cout << "------ end ------" << endl;
}

void getInfo1th(vector< pair<string, int> >& pair_vec)
{

    pair_vec.clear();

    cout << "Enter author's information(name and age):" << endl;
    string name;
    int age;
    pair<string, int> next_auth;
    while (cin >> name >> age) {
        next_auth = make_pair(name, age);
        pair_vec.push_back(next_auth);
    }

    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    cin.clear();
}

void getInfo2nd(vector< pair<string, int> >& pair_vec)
{

    pair_vec.clear();

    cout << "Enter author's information(name and age):" << endl;
    pair<string, int> next_auth;
    while (cin >> next_auth.first >> next_auth.second) {
        pair_vec.push_back(next_auth);
    }
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    cin.clear();
}

void getInfo3rd(vector< pair<string, int> >& pair_vec)
{
    pair_vec.clear();
    cout << "Enter author's information(name and age):" << endl;
    string name;
    int age;
    pair<string, int> next_auth;
    while (cin >> name >> age) {
        next_auth = pair<string, int>(name, age);
        pair_vec.push_back(next_auth);
    }

    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    cin.clear();
}

int main(void)
{
    vector< pair<string, int> > pair_vec;
    getInfo1th(pair_vec);
    printInfo(pair_vec);

    getInfo2nd(pair_vec);
    printInfo(pair_vec);

    getInfo3rd(pair_vec);
    printInfo(pair_vec);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, test it as following:

1. Enter author's information(name and age):

   - re 23
   - dsds 23
   - ds df
   - --- Authors' information: ------

     - re 23
     - dsds 23
   - ----- end ------
2. Enter author's information(name and age):

   - fdf 23
   - ---- Authors' information: ------
   - ----- end ------
3. Enter author's information(name and age):

   - dsd 23
   - dfd 23
   - sds df
   - ---- Authors' information: ------

     - fdf 23
     - dsd 23
     - dfd 23
   - ----- end ------

The second method cannot work well. I also test it alone， but it worked. I thought, the error may relate with the vector's function clear.I tried to use the erase, it worked like as before.

Comment: Please tell us what kind of output you get, and what do you expect?

Comment: We cannot magically divine what you instead expected to be achieved by only reading code that, by your own admission, _doesn't achieve that thing_!

Comment: @Venemo,@ Lightness Races in Orbit, I am so sorry. the program just reads the string and a int to make pair and store into vector.Then print them. I just written 3 methods to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with `std::cin` and clearing its error flag. If the error flag is set, no further operations can succeed on `std::cin`. You need to clear the error flag first. Change:

```
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
cin.clear();
```

to:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
```

and it should be fine.

**Explanation why**

In this line:

```
while (cin >> name >> age)
```

you read from `STDIN` until an error occurs. If an error occurs then an error flag is set and future attempts to get input will fail. No further operations can succeed on `std::cin` until you reset the error state. That's why you call

```
cin.clear();
```

to get rid of the error flag. Now it makes sense to proceed. You note that the input failed (in `getInfo1th()`) because there's something that you don't want to read (it's *df* in the input that you pasted). When you try to get input again (in `getInfo2nd()`), it will read the same input in the buffer (i.e. *df*) and it will fail again. That's why you want to jump to the next line by executing this:

```
cin.ignore(1000, `\n`);
```

Comment: \@banach-space,Thanks. Last night, after the shower, I debug it write. I did that like yours. Any way, thanks very much.